# Download enterprise.wsdl.xml from Salesforce

Tags: php, xml, web-services, wsdl, salesforce

I'm trying to configure this package https://github.com/davispeixoto/Laravel-5-Salesforce

in my laravel app

---

## Expecting

```
return [
    'username' => 'YOUR_SALESFORCE_USERNAME',
    'password' => 'YOUR_SALESFORCE_PASSWORD',
    'token' => 'YOUR_SALESFORCE_TOKEN',
    'wsdl' => 'path/to/your/enterprise.wsdl.xml',
];
```

---

It have **3** parameters.

```
    'username' => 'YOUR_SALESFORCE_USERNAME',
    'password' => 'YOUR_SALESFORCE_PASSWORD',
    'token' => 'YOUR_SALESFORCE_TOKEN',
```

But I'm not sure what is

```
    `'wsdl' => 'path/to/your/enterprise.wsdl.xml',`
```

---

Where and how do I get `enterprise.wsdl.xml` ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in to your Salesforce account. You must log in as an
   administrator or as a user who has the “Modify All Data” permission.

   ---
2. From Setup, enter API in the Quick Find box, then select API.

---

3. Click Generate Metadata WSDL and save the XML WSDL file to your file system.

---

4. Click Generate Enterprise WSDL and save the XML WSDL file to
       your file system.